# validating the Aadhar card number in a application

Tags: java, spring-mvc

we are developing a application which need to check whether user entering valid "AADHAR" number or not. i find some links and some "apis" but didn't meet final requirement please provide me a some useful material to solve this

[**What is Aadhaar?**](http://uidai.gov.in/what-is-aadhaar.html)

Aadhaar is a 12 digit individual identification number issued by the Unique Identification Authority of India on behalf of the Government of India.

Comment: Do you want to just check the number or validate that Aadhar card?

Comment: yes i need to check  the number which was given by user is exist or not

Comment: This is very vague question, Do you just want to check the format of the number or you actually want to validate it against the database aswell? Please provide more details.

Comment: i need to validate against the database.

Comment: You have to ask from TCS and Home ministry for the API access. It is a secure and confidential thing and it can't have any public API

Comment: please find a solution which validate the number against the database

Comment: https://developer.uidai.gov.in/site/book/export/html/18

Comment: It's just like validating [Social Security number (SSN)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_Security_number)?

Comment: Dinesh Saini i found some apis in developer.uidai.gov.in but it was not working properly here for all numbers

Comment: ashokhein which is of no use already i tried tje api to validate but it is of no use

Comment: yup its like validating Social Security number

Comment: @SunkariKiran I think you just want to validate that ADDHAR card no. is in correct format?

Comment: Do you use Webservices for Validation?

Comment: Refer this link for verhoeff in all languages https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Checksums/Verhoeff_Algorithm

Comment: @DineshSaini I think "It was supposed to be a secure and confidential thing" but not "It is a secure and confidential thing"

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think you are looking for `Verhoeff algorithm`, because UIDAI uses this algorithm for validating the aadhar number. You just need to create and use below class.

```
class VerhoeffAlgorithm{
        static int[][] d  = new int[][]
                {
                        {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
                        {1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5},
                        {2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6},
                        {3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7},
                        {4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8},
                        {5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1},
                        {6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2},
                        {7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3},
                        {8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4},
                        {9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0}
                };
        static int[][] p = new int[][]
                {
                        {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9},
                        {1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4},
                        {5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2},
                        {8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7},
                        {9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0},
                        {4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1},
                        {2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5},
                        {7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8}
                };
        static int[] inv = {0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

        public static boolean validateVerhoeff(String num){
            int c = 0;
            int[] myArray = StringToReversedIntArray(num);
            for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
                c = d[c][p[(i % 8)][myArray[i]]];
            }

            return (c == 0);
        }
        private static int[] StringToReversedIntArray(String num){
            int[] myArray = new int[num.length()];
            for(int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++){
                myArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(num.substring(i, i + 1));
            }
            myArray = Reverse(myArray);
            return myArray;
        }
        private static int[] Reverse(int[] myArray){
            int[] reversed = new int[myArray.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < myArray.length ; i++){
                reversed[i] = myArray[myArray.length - (i + 1)];
            }
            return reversed;
        }
    }
```

For More Info:-

1. [Verhoeff_Algorithm](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Checksums/Verhoeff_Algorithm)
2. [Google groups, Aadhar auth](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/aadhaarauth/eB5hOU-Qtq0)
3. [Actual aadhaaar is 11 digits long and not 12](http://simplybanking.wordpress.com/2013/07/14/the-actual-uidai-aadhaar-number-is-11-digits-long-and-not-12-digits/)

---

**EDIT:--**

```
public static boolean validateAadharNumber(String aadharNumber){
        Pattern aadharPattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{12}");
        boolean isValidAadhar = aadharPattern.matcher(aadharNumber).matches();
        if(isValidAadhar){
            isValidAadhar = VerhoeffAlgorithm.validateVerhoeff(aadharNumber);
        }
        return isValidAadhar;
    }
```

Comment: thank you its workin good  and if we impose a condition that it length must be  equal to 12

Comment: Indeed you are right,we will have to check the length explicitly,i have deleted my previous statement. just updated my answer for length check!!!

Comment: Refer this link for verhoeff in all languages https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Checksums/Verhoeff_Algorithm

Comment: Just to add ,also check if the number begins with 0 or 1 if no then it is valid.

Comment: RegEx and Verhoeff_Algorithm will not only work, As I have also tested on some number like "9999 9999 9999" This is Valid Aadhar number as per Verhoeff_Algorithm as well as Aadhar api which is incorrect. What I want is verifying if the number is really belongs to some individual or not.

Comment: How can we validate Aadhaar VID?

Comment: any suggestion in dart language? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

### python3

```
def aadharNumVerify(adharNum: str) -> bool:
    """
    Takes a N digit aadhar number and
    returns a boolean value whether that is Correct or Not
    """
    verhoeff_table_d = (
        (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
        (1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5),
        (2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6),
        (3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7),
        (4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8),
        (5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1),
        (6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2),
        (7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3),
        (8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4),
        (9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0))

    verhoeff_table_p = (
        (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
        (1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4),
        (5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2),
        (8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7),
        (9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0),
        (4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1),
        (2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5),
        (7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8))

    # verhoeff_table_inv = (0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)

    def checksum(s: str) -> int:
        """For a given number generates a Verhoeff digit and
        returns number + digit"""
        c = 0
        for i, item in enumerate(reversed(s)):
            c = verhoeff_table_d[c][verhoeff_table_p[i % 8][int(item)]]
        return c

    # Validate Verhoeff checksum
    return checksum(adharNum) == 0 and len(adharNum) == 12
```

Answer (score 2):

**Objective C for iOS**

import "AadhaarValidate.h"

```
@implementation AadhaarValidate

int _multiplicationTable[][10] = {
    { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
    { 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5 },
    { 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6 },
    { 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7 },
    { 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8 },
    { 5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1 },
    { 6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2 },
    { 7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3 },
    { 8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4 },
    { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 }
};
int _permutationTable[][10] = {
    { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 },
    { 1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4 },
    { 5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2 },
    { 8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7 },
    { 9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0 },
    { 4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1 },
    { 2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5 },
    { 7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8 }
};
int _inverseTable[] = { 0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
+(BOOL)isValidateAadhaar:(NSString *)aaDhaarNumber{
    int c = 0;
    int len = (int)[aaDhaarNumber length];

    const char *numberInChar = [aaDhaarNumber UTF8String];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        c = _multiplicationTable[c][_permutationTable[(i % 8)][numberInCharenter code here[len - i - 1] - '0']];
    return c == 0;
}
@end
**Test**
> NSLog(@"Check aadhar number:%d",[AadhaarValidate
> isValidateAadhaar:@"*******"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use this javascript**

```js
// multiplication table d
var d = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5],
  [2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6],
  [3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7],
  [4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8],
  [5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1],
  [6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2],
  [7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3],
  [8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4],
  [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
];

// permutation table p
var p = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4],
  [5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2],
  [8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7],
  [9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0],
  [4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1],
  [2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5],
  [7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8]
];

// inverse table inv
var inv = [0, 4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

// converts string or number to an array and inverts it
function invArray(array) {

  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(array) === "[object Number]") {
    array = String(array);
  }

  if (Object.prototype.toString.call(array) === "[object String]") {
    array = array.split("").map(Number);
  }

  return array.reverse();

}

// generates checksum
function generate(array) {

  var c = 0;
  var invertedArray = invArray(array);

  for (var i = 0; i < invertedArray.length; i++) {
    c = d[c][p[((i + 1) % 8)][invertedArray[i]]];
  }

  return inv[c];
}

// validates checksum
function validate(array) {

  var c = 0;
  var invertedArray = invArray(array);

  for (var i = 0; i < invertedArray.length; i++) {
    c = d[c][p[(i % 8)][invertedArray[i]]];
  }

  return (c === 0);
}

var g_aadhar_num = "";
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#aadhaar_number_op")[0].innerText = "Enter 12 digits...";
  $('#aadhaar_number').keyup(function() {
      $("#aadhaar_number_op")[0].innerText = "Enter " + (12 - $('#aadhaar_number')[0].value.length) + " more digits...";
      if ($('#aadhaar_number')[0].value.length == 12) {
        g_aadhar_num = $('#aadhaar_number')[0].value;
        if (validate($('#aadhaar_number')[0].value) == true) {
          $("#aadhaar_number_op").attr("style", "color:green");
          $("#aadhaar_number_op")[0].innerText = "Checksum Pass!"
        } else {
          $("#aadhaar_number_op").attr("style", "color:red");
          $("#aadhaar_number_op")[0].innerText = "Checksum Fail! Invalid Aadhar"
        }
      } else if($('#aadhaar_number')[0].value.length > 12) {
      $("#aadhaar_number_op")[0].innerText = "can't enter more than 12 digits...";
      $('#aadhaar_number')[0].value = g_aadhar_num;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="aadhaar_number" class="col-lg-5 control-label">Aadhaar Number&nbsp;<span style="color: red">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-lg-7 ">
    <input maxlength="12" type="number" class="form-control" id="aadhaar_number" name="aadhaar_no" placeholder="Aadhaar Number" required="">
    <p id="aadhaar_number_op"></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Courtesy**
[Wikipedia](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Checksums/Verhoeff_Algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

### KOTLIN

```kotlin
    fun isAadhaarValid(aadhaarNo: String): Boolean {
        //Removed extra characters
        val newAadhaarNo = aadhaarNo.replace("-", "", true)

        if (newAadhaarNo.length != 12
            || newAadhaarNo.toBigIntegerOrNull() == null
            || newAadhaarNo.first().toString().toInt() in 0..1
        ) {
            return false
        }

        val firstMatrix = arrayOf(
            intArrayOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
            intArrayOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5),
            intArrayOf(2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 7, 8, 9, 5, 6),
            intArrayOf(3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 5, 6, 7),
            intArrayOf(4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 9, 5, 6, 7, 8),
            intArrayOf(5, 9, 8, 7, 6, 0, 4, 3, 2, 1),
            intArrayOf(6, 5, 9, 8, 7, 1, 0, 4, 3, 2),
            intArrayOf(7, 6, 5, 9, 8, 2, 1, 0, 4, 3),
            intArrayOf(8, 7, 6, 5, 9, 3, 2, 1, 0, 4),
            intArrayOf(9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0)
        )
        val secondMatrix = arrayOf(
            intArrayOf(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
            intArrayOf(1, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 3, 0, 9, 4),
            intArrayOf(5, 8, 0, 3, 7, 9, 6, 1, 4, 2),
            intArrayOf(8, 9, 1, 6, 0, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7),
            intArrayOf(9, 4, 5, 3, 1, 2, 6, 8, 7, 0),
            intArrayOf(4, 2, 8, 6, 5, 7, 3, 9, 0, 1),
            intArrayOf(2, 7, 9, 3, 8, 0, 6, 4, 1, 5),
            intArrayOf(7, 0, 4, 6, 9, 1, 3, 2, 5, 8)
        )

        var isValid = 0

        //Created reverse array
        val reversedIntArray = newAadhaarNo.chunked(1).map { it.toInt() }.toIntArray().reversedArray()

        //Apply Verhoeff algorithm
        for (i in reversedIntArray.indices) {
            isValid = firstMatrix[isValid][secondMatrix[i % 8][reversedIntArray[i]]]
        }
        return isValid == 0
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this one.

```
function validateAadhaar1(fieldData){                        

    console.log(fieldData.id);
    var lengthOfAadhaar = fieldData.value;                        

    var checkDigits = /^\d+$/.test(lengthOfAadhaar);

    var zero  =  /.!=000000000000/.test(lengthOfAadhaar); 
    var one   =  /.!=111111111111/.test(lengthOfAadhaar);
    var two   =  /.!=222222222222/.test(lengthOfAadhaar);
    var three =  /.!=333333333333/.test(lengthOfAadhaar);
    var four =   /.!=444444444444/.test(lengthOfAadhaar);
    var five =   /.!=555555555555/.test(lengthOfAadhaar);
    var six =    /.!=666666666666/.test(lengthOfAadhaar);
    var seven =  /.!=777777777777/.test(lengthOfAadhaar);
    var eight =  /.!=888888888888/.test(lengthOfAadhaar);
    var nine =   /.!=999999999999/.test(lengthOfAadhaar);


    if(lengthOfAadhaar.length!=12 || checkDigits == false || zero == false || one ==false || two ==false ||
        three == false || four == false || five == false || six == false || seven == false || eight == false 
        || nine == false)
    {               

        document.getElementById(fieldData.id).style.color = "#ff0202";    

        return false;

    } else{                         

        document.getElementById(fieldData.id).style.color = "#555";      

    }
    return true;
}
```