# Is there any way to get aadhar card verification in flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, api

I want to verify aadhar card number in a way like when a user enters his/her aadhar number OTP will be sent to the link mobile number with provided aadhar number. Is there any API or any way to achieve this functionality in flutter?

Comment: hi, interesting, perhaps this might be of interest https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686384/validating-the-aadhar-card-number-in-a-application

Answer (score 2):

Please try this regex

```
regex = “^[2-9]{1}[0-9]{3}\\s[0-9]{4}\\s[0-9]{4}$”;
```

Answer (score 1):

● Aadhar auth can be done in flutter!
**[UIDAI](https://uidai.gov.in/) provides an API with which you can do that** .
Go to uidai.gov.in and read documents related to "Aadhar Authentication Api" you will also need necessary demographic and biometric details for authentication.

● for more about how to integrate Adhar read this article [LinkToArticle](https://veri5digital.com/veri5-blog/how-to-integrate-aadhaar-auth-api/),

● or else you can use `Verhoeff algorithm` , this link will help you to get that [validating the Aadhar card number in a application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27686384/validating-the-aadhar-card-number-in-a-application)